# SKU non-Default label is not reflected on the frontend in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, sku, magento-catalog

I am trying to change the SKU attribute label from "SKU" to "Item" on the Product Page on the storefront by adding a label to the attribute in Admin Panel by going to

> Stores > Attributes > Product

selecting "SKU" attribute in the grid and adding a label under

> Manage Labels > Default Store View

column.

It seems that the attribute label for SKU which is displayed on the Product Page on the storefront will only change if I modify the Default Label in Admin Panel.

All other attributes are properly reflected on the storefront (e.g. color, size, etc).

During my investigation, I have found out that the template responsible for rendering the SKU is `module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`. However, the attribute label is not translatable therefore I cannot use translations files to change the attribute label. On the other side, I understand why the attributes displayed via above template are not translatable as - I think - the attributes labels should be changed from the Admin Panel via Manage Labels facility as described above.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that Magento shows always the attribute's frontend label and not the attribute's store label in that template.
You can fix that by replacing the line 26 in the file

```
module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml
```

with the code line below

```
$_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
```